# Setting up AjaxControlToolkit 4.0 with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-ajax

I have downloaded a fresh copy of VS2013 and created a web site. I want to be able to use the AjacControlToolkit 4.0 (Dec 2013 Build), so I downloaded the latest version, added it to my project and made a reference to it in master page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

By default VS adds the following script manager control to the master page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle"/>
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

So I change the script manager to ToolkitScriptManager:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle"/>
    </Scripts>
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Add a simple ajax control:

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="xxx" Text="dddd"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ComboBox>
```

And I get the following error:

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution!**

First remove the reference to:

```
Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll
```

And in the `packages.config` file, comment out this line:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.MSAjax" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

In your `asp:ToolScriptManager`, comment out this line:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
```

Do a clean build, then do a build.

Hope this helps someone, as it took hours to figure out!